# i recover my metamask account, but the 2 accounts created there is no longer in my main account

Tags: metamask

I recovered my account via my secret word. upon log in my 2 accounts that I created within my main account is no longer there, how can I recover those. I have there wallet address. I created under my account the metamask of my 2 relatives, I submited there wallet address ,the company forwarded amount in there wallet address, how can I recover there accounts I made under my accounts because after I recover my account only my account was there, the 2 accounts I created are no longer there.

Comment: click on + create account

Comment: are the other two accounts on a different chain? Like BSC? I guess, if the accounts don't have any funds on mainnet, they won't be added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

All of the accounts that get created happen the exact same way each time you restore a wallet. Just keep hitting "new" until you get to however many account you had before and the account ids will all line up perfectly. Then you have to add whatever names you gave them by hand.